# Get progress value using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have created windows application and done a MSI silent installation using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll.

How can I monitor the progress value the of MSI and installation status?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you use the ExternalUIRecord delegate, that's the callback that handles every aspect of the UI. If you sign up to handle the UI you're doing all of it, not just progress, so you'll need to deal with errors, Files-In-Use dialogs etc.

The callback will give you records of the InstallMessage enumeration that tell you what they are about. To initialize this you call SetExternalUI for the record-based callback. Then install the MSI from that same thread with an install call.

This is C++ but gives you the overall outline of it all:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309215(v=vs.85).aspx

as does this for the non-record callback:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368786(v=vs.85).aspx